# Can data model be changed in CloudKit after App is in App Store and Container is in production mode?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

What happens if I figure out I need an other entity in `CloudKit` and container is already operational, people are using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During development, you can make any changes you need. When you deploy to the Production environment, Apple warns you:

> After the schema is deployed, you won't be able to remove Production
>   types or attributes in Development.

So you can add types and attributes, you just can't remove them. You can also add and remove indexes.